# Arguments stops being evaluated inside tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

In the following example, the code `\textwidth-1mm` is "evaluated" in the first page, but on the second page (where I add a node around it), the text is not evaluated anymore and I can see a bit `-1mm` in the middle of the page... Why? How could I correct that?

Thank!

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster width=\textwidth-1mm, raster height=\textheight]
  \tcbitem[blankest,valign=center]
  \tcbox[]{
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }
\end{tcbitemize}
\newpage

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt]{
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster width=\textwidth-1mm, raster height=\textheight]
      \tcbitem[blankest,valign=center]
      \tcbox[]{
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
      }
    \end{tcbitemize}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: On my TeXLive 2018 installation I fail to reproduce these issues when I compile your code with `pdflatex`. Which TeX installation are you using, and which compiler?

Comment: @marmot I'm using TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian, pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19

Comment: Weird. I have 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 as well.

Comment: Hum... I have the full example here: http://paste.debian.net/1073867

Comment: @marmot and it's funny, if I add a minipage around tcbitemize, the problem disapears.

Comment: On my MikTeX installation, your code compile without any problem. By the way, do you know command `\tcbincludegraphics`? And second, what do you want to do with the `node` around the raster?

Comment: @igasi : Uhm what a strange problem!  Even lualatex has issue with it. And no I was not aware of tcbincludegraphics, what's the advantage over classical includegraphics? And my goal is to find a way to overlay perfectly two boxes like in my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480411/overlay-of-tcbitems-are-not-well-aligned

Comment: @marmot : I tried also on another computer running pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/NixOS.org) and I have exactly the same problem. Are you looking at the second page? (first page is just to show what I would expect)

Comment: @Ignasi same comment as for marmot, I tried on another computer and same issue: you are looking at page 2 right?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at p. 2, and there is no problem.