# Overlay of tcbitems are not well aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, overlays

I'd like to be able to overlay several tables made from raster/tcbitems. I tried several methods to do that, but none of them work for me. There is always a margin somewhere that is wrong. This example uses:

```
\mbox{\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0cm{ <text> }}}
```

Any idea how to have exact overlay? Thanks!

[image]

**MWE**: (sorry, it's not super minimal, but the code for rasters can be seen as a "blackbox" and just be copy pasted)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newlength{\myPaperWidth}
\setlength{\myPaperWidth}{297mm}
\newlength{\myPaperHeight}
\setlength{\myPaperHeight}{210mm}
\newlength{\myRightMargin}
\setlength{\myRightMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myRightPadding}
\setlength{\myRightPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\myLeftMargin}
\setlength{\myLeftMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myLeftPadding}
\setlength{\myLeftPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\myTopMargin}
\setlength{\myTopMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myTopPadding}
\setlength{\myTopPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\myBottomMargin}
\setlength{\myBottomMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myBottomPadding}
\setlength{\myBottomPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\mystockwidth}
\setlength{\mystockwidth}{\myPaperWidth}
\addtolength{\mystockwidth}{\myLeftMargin}
\addtolength{\mystockwidth}{\myRightMargin}
\newlength{\mystockheight}
\setlength{\mystockheight}{\myPaperHeight}
\addtolength{\mystockheight}{\myTopMargin}
\addtolength{\mystockheight}{\myBottomMargin}
\usepackage[  paperwidth=\myPaperWidth,paperheight=\myPaperHeight, hmargin={\myLeftPadding, \myRightPadding}, vmargin={\myTopPadding, \myBottomPadding}, nohead, nofoot, nomarginpar, pdftex=false, dvips=false, vtex=false,driver=none,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[width=\the\mystockwidth,height=\the\mystockheight,center,pdftex,frame,noinfo]{crop}


\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}

\noindent %%%% FIRST IMAGE
\begin{tcbitemize}[,nobeforeafter, blankest, raster row skip=4mm, raster columns=1, raster rows=1, raster valign=center, halign=center, raster every box/.style={nobeforeafter,fit=outside,top=0pt, bottom=0pt, right=0pt, left=0pt, boxsep=0pt,enhanced,clip upper,halign=center, raster valign=center}, raster width=\textwidth, raster column skip=4mm, raster height=\textheight, raster height=1\textheight, ]
  \tcbitem[blankest,valign=center]
  \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
  \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
  \tcbox[,nobeforeafter, enhanced, skin=enhanced jigsaw, clip upper, left=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt, right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, beforeafter skip=0pt, tikz={,}, ]{
    \includegraphics[width=\tcbitemtw,height=\tcbitemth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }
\end{tcbitemize}
\newpage

\noindent %%%% SECOND IMAGE
\begin{tcbitemize}[,nobeforeafter, blankest, raster row skip=4mm, raster columns=1, raster rows=1, raster valign=center, halign=center, raster every box/.style={nobeforeafter,fit=outside,top=0pt, bottom=0pt, right=0pt, left=0pt, boxsep=0pt,enhanced,clip upper,halign=center, raster valign=center}, raster width=\textwidth, raster column skip=4mm, raster height=\textheight, raster height=1\textheight, ]\tcbitem[blankest,valign=center]
  \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
  \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
  \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster rows=2,raster height=\tcbtextheight,raster width=\tcbtextwidth, raster valign=center]
    \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multirow=1]{
      \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
      \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
      \begin{tcbitemize}[raster rows=1,raster columns=100,raster height=\tcbtextheight,raster width=\tcbtextwidth, raster valign=center]
        \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=40]{
          \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
          \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
        }
        \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=60]{
          \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
          \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
          \tcbox[,nobeforeafter, enhanced, skin=enhanced jigsaw, clip upper, left=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt, right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, beforeafter skip=0pt, tikz={,}, ]{
            \includegraphics[width=\tcbitemtw,height=\tcbitemth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
          }
        }
      \end{tcbitemize}
    }
    \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multirow=1]{
      \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
      \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
      \begin{tcbitemize}[raster rows=1,raster columns=100,raster height=\tcbtextheight,raster width=\tcbtextwidth, raster valign=center]
        \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=60]{
          \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
          \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
        }
        \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=40]{
          \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
          \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
        }
      \end{tcbitemize}
    }
  \end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcbitemize}
\newpage

\noindent %%%% MIX OF IMAGES
\mbox{\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0cm{%%%% First picture
      \begin{tcbitemize}[,nobeforeafter, blankest, raster row skip=4mm, raster columns=1, raster rows=1, raster valign=center, halign=center, raster every box/.style={nobeforeafter,fit=outside,top=0pt, bottom=0pt, right=0pt, left=0pt, boxsep=0pt,enhanced,clip upper,halign=center, raster valign=center}, raster width=\textwidth, raster column skip=4mm, raster height=\textheight, raster height=1\textheight, ]
        \tcbitem[blankest,valign=center]
        \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
        \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
        \tcbox[,nobeforeafter, enhanced, skin=enhanced jigsaw, clip upper, left=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt, right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, beforeafter skip=0pt, tikz={,}, ]{
          \includegraphics[width=\tcbitemtw,height=\tcbitemth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
        }
      \end{tcbitemize}
    }}}%
\mbox{\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0cm{%%%%% Second picture
      \begin{tcbitemize}[,nobeforeafter, blankest, raster row skip=4mm, raster columns=1, raster rows=1, raster valign=center, halign=center, raster every box/.style={nobeforeafter,fit=outside,top=0pt, bottom=0pt, right=0pt, left=0pt, boxsep=0pt,enhanced,clip upper,halign=center, raster valign=center}, raster width=\textwidth, raster column skip=4mm, raster height=\textheight, raster height=1\textheight, ]\tcbitem[blankest,valign=center]
        \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
        \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
        \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster rows=2,raster height=\tcbtextheight,raster width=\tcbtextwidth, raster valign=center]
          \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multirow=1]{
            \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
            \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
            \begin{tcbitemize}[raster rows=1,raster columns=100,raster height=\tcbtextheight,raster width=\tcbtextwidth, raster valign=center]
              \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=40]{
                \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
                \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
              }
              \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=60]{
                \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
                \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
                \tcbox[,nobeforeafter, enhanced, skin=enhanced jigsaw, clip upper, left=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt, right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, beforeafter skip=0pt, tikz={,}, ]{
                  \includegraphics[width=\tcbitemtw,height=\tcbitemth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
                }
              }
            \end{tcbitemize}
          }
          \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multirow=1]{
            \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
            \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
            \begin{tcbitemize}[raster rows=1,raster columns=100,raster height=\tcbtextheight,raster width=\tcbtextwidth, raster valign=center]
              \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=60]{
                \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
                \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
              }
              \tcbitem[blankest, valign=center,raster multicolumn=40]{
                \edef\tcbitemtw{\tcbtextwidth}
                \edef\tcbitemth{\tcbtextheight}
              }
            \end{tcbitemize}
          }
        \end{tcbitemize}
      \end{tcbitemize}
    }
  }
}
\newpage


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `tcolorbox`, you could use a `tcbposter` instead of a `tcbraster`. This way it's easy to place boxes wherever you want. You can even place boxes over previous ones without `TikZ` nodes and `remember picture` and `overlays`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newlength{\myPaperWidth}
\setlength{\myPaperWidth}{297mm}
\newlength{\myPaperHeight}
\setlength{\myPaperHeight}{210mm}
\newlength{\myRightMargin}
\setlength{\myRightMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myRightPadding}
\setlength{\myRightPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\myLeftMargin}
\setlength{\myLeftMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myLeftPadding}
\setlength{\myLeftPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\myTopMargin}
\setlength{\myTopMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myTopPadding}
\setlength{\myTopPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\myBottomMargin}
\setlength{\myBottomMargin}{5mm}
\newlength{\myBottomPadding}
\setlength{\myBottomPadding}{5mm}
\newlength{\mystockwidth}
\setlength{\mystockwidth}{\myPaperWidth}
\addtolength{\mystockwidth}{\myLeftMargin}
\addtolength{\mystockwidth}{\myRightMargin}
\newlength{\mystockheight}
\setlength{\mystockheight}{\myPaperHeight}
\addtolength{\mystockheight}{\myTopMargin}
\addtolength{\mystockheight}{\myBottomMargin}
\usepackage[  paperwidth=\myPaperWidth,paperheight=\myPaperHeight, hmargin={\myLeftPadding, \myRightPadding}, vmargin={\myTopPadding, \myBottomPadding}, nohead, nofoot, nomarginpar, pdftex=false, dvips=false, vtex=false,driver=none, showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[width=\the\mystockwidth,
height=\the\mystockheight,
center,
pdftex,
frame,
noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster={columns=1, rows=1}
]
\posterbox[blankest]{row=1,column=1}{\includegraphics[width=\tcbpostercolwidth,height=\tcbposterrowheight]{example-image-a}}
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
\noindent\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster={columns=2, rows=2, spacing=0pt}
]
\posterbox[blankest]{row=1,column=1, rowspan=2, span=2}{\includegraphics[width=\tcbposterwidth,height=\tcbposterheight]{example-image-a}}
\posterbox[blankest]{row=1,column=2}{\includegraphics[width=\tcbpostercolwidth,height=\tcbposterrowheight]{example-image-b}}
\posterbox[blankest]{column=1, above=bottom}{\includegraphics[width=\tcbpostercolwidth,height=\tcbposterrowheight]{example-image-c}}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the trick, indeed it should work for this specific problem. But I'm curious also to see a generic way to do averlay, (it may be possible that I don't have only raster, but also random raw text... especially because it will be generated by a script). Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: @tobiasBora I don't understand the question. You can put whatever you want inside a `tcbposterbox`. About overlaying, maybe you should consider `beamer` instead of a regular `article`.

Comment: Hum, actually using a poster of size 1x1 and positionning everything inside this poster at position 1x1 allows me to do what I want ^^

Comment: indeed, I can embed rasters inside the poster! (my script for now nest lot's of rasters together... Maybe I should consider using poster at some points). Thanks!